# How to properly do user authentication and maintain session with Tornado?

Tags: python, session, authentication, cookies, tornado

I have a Tornado web app and I use Google Oauth Mixin and Facebook Graph Mixin for login. Once I authorize the user, I would save his email in the cookie:

```
self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user['email'])
```

and in subsequent requests, I would check if cookie is set or not. If it is set then I would take email from cookie and query database with that email.

I am encrypting it with a `cookie_secret` so email is not available in plain text. So today I used another email, logged in and made note of its cookie value. And then I logged in with my main email id, edited the cookie value that of another user and refreshed the page. Now I can see contents of another user by his cookie value!

So how do I solve this problem? Or is it okay that if someone gets to my cookies they can always login as me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Jeff](http://blog.codinghorror.com/protecting-your-cookies-httponly/) the solution is simple. Make cookies `httpOnly`

While creating cookie, pass this as `True`.

```
self.set_secure_cookie('trakr', user['email'], httpOnly=True)
```